# How can I moderate comments in the Facebook fb:comments social plugin?

Tags: facebook

I've got a facebook application that is on a Canvas page and I'm viewing it through a Facebook Page tab. The like button works, the comments work and the delete button works(I've got candelete on). In the facebook documentation though, it says that the moderators of the application can moderate comments through a link by the post button. How do I get that button to show up? And how do I get notifications to work? I've got my user id in the attributes for the comments.

I've tried to initialize the sdk with the asyncronous code and my app id but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({ 
appId: '115173993418',
status: true,
cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My dear there are two ways to do this. First if you are the developer of the application, when you put comment box on your page and login through it, the plugin shows a link "Administer Comment" below the post button. Click on that button you will see a small window where you can set your moderator.
the other way to set moderator is to add a meta tag

```
<meta property="fb:moderator" content="FACEBOOK-PROFILE-ID"/>
```

I hope it will work

Comment: Ah yes thank you. The administer comments shows up on the stand-alone application page but not the application when it is within a Page Tab.

Comment: And now I've changed something and it's gone again. The meta property doesn't work for me as I'm within a tab on a facebook page and for some reason the Adminster Comment link only comes up sometimes. I'm logged in as the only Developer on the application and have looked at it in a tab and just on the application page.Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I'm using the javascript sdk and the fb:comments plugin but the app has to be of type iframe to view the moderate comments link. It doesn't work in the Canvas type.

Comment: I suppose this `meta` tag was changed, and does not work anymore. One can add a friend as moderator using the GUI button underneath the post message. But I find this friending clients and what not just for adding them as moderator silly.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the moderator tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=APP_ID

and moderate the comments. You can also moderate in any page that loads your comment plugin. All admins and moderators can moderate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="275791699247614"/>
```

you can try putting the above meta tag in your page.. then access your mod tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=YOURAPPID&view=recent_comments